# How to use button to get a Jquery Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datechooser

I want to create a Datechooser, but I want a button near the text field and when I click the button, the Datepicker should show up, but selected date should be in the text box.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try jQuery UI DatePicker.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

Demo from jQuery UI site: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Comment: Thanks a lot, i wasn't picky enough to look at the demos tabs... thanks anyway...